# Simple Differential Equations Question.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question reads:

Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be arbitrary constants. For each of the following $y(x)$, find a differential equation that y satisfies, with the order of the ODE equal to the number of arbitrary constants in $y(x)$. The ODE should not contain any arbitrary constants.

(a)   $y(x) = cos(x) + C_1x^2$

Could someone explain what is really going on in this question because I can't seem to get the intuition behind it. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isolate the constant, for example with

$$\frac{y(x)}{x^2}=\frac{\cos x}{x^2}+C_1.$$

Then taking the derivative, you eliminate it.

$$\left(\frac{y(x)}{x^2}\right)'=\left(\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\right)'.$$

Now you can expand/reshape this equation (an ODE) the way you like. For example, the linear form

$$x^2y'(x)-2x\,y(x)=-x^2\sin x-2x\cos x.$$

---

Another example with two constants:

$$y=ax^b.$$

Isolate $a$ by taking the logarithm:

$$\log y=a+b\log x.$$

Differentiate:

$$\frac{y'}y=\frac bx.$$

Isolate $b$:

$$\frac{xy'}y=b.$$

Differentiate:

$$\left(\frac{xy'}y\right)'=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

If you had to do this with

(i) $y(x) = x + C_1$. Simply deriving $y$ makes $C_1$ disappear, answer would thus be : $y'(x) = 1$.

(ii) $y(x) = C_1 \exp( x)$, answer would be $y'/y = 1$. This time, $y'$ still contains $C_1$, so $y'=C_1 \exp(x)$ is not the answer. But $y'/y = 1$ which doesn't contain $C_1$, so this is a valid answer.

Does it help understand what is expected?

Comment: Yes this helps a lot. Is the question essentially just asking me to manipulate the derivative of the equation given, to form a differential equation without any arbitrary constants?

Answer (score 0):

i this equation you got only 1 constant, therefor you need to build a first order O.D.E:
$y=cosx+C1x^2 $
so:$ y'=-sinx+2C1x$. 
lets mult the second equation by $-0.5x$ to get:
$-0.5xy'=0.5xsinx-C1x^2 $.

adding both equation gives:
$y-0.5xy'=cosx+0.5xsinx$
the solution to this equation is (a).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to isolate the constant

$$ \frac{y-\cos x}{x^2} = C_1 $$

Then differentiate both sides

$$ \frac{x^2(y'+\sin x) - 2x(y-\cos x)}{x^4} = 0 $$

$$ \implies x^2(y'+\sin x) - 2x(y-\cos x) = 0 $$

This is your ODE.